# How to get page count of pdf byte array generated through SSRS

Tags: c#, pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, arrays

My task is to get page count of a pdf content. I made use of SSRS tools to generate pdf byte array. Once I get byte array I need to get the page count of this byte array generated. C# is the programming language used.

Currently I am creating a pdf file physically, using the generated pdf byte array. Later I am opening the pdf file in the memory and getting the page count. Finally I am deleting the file that has been created for temporary purpose.

Is there any way to get the page count of the generated pdf byte array without creating a physical file? Or can I create a pdf file object in the memory?

PDF creation needs extra security permissions and we don't use pdf file for any other purpose.

Comment: What is the method through which you create a PDF File? Can you elaborate on what you meant by  "creating file physically"?

Comment: Writing file onto physical location

Comment: API of some sor which deals with PDF processing can do the trick here. But I dont know your constraints in using the same though .. Have a look at http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/ or iText Api

Comment: pdfsharp deals with pdf files. Currently i could able to create pdf file, but I don't want to create a file. Without creating a file I am trying to get the page count.

Comment: I have not tested this just blind copy paste.. 

From http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fa3313dd-e81a-42fb-8a4c-fe41dbb4d985/print-local-report-problem?forum=sqlreportingservices  

//Create Byte array containing the rendered image. of the 1st page. 
 Byte[] firstPage = report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIDs, out warnings); 
int m_numberOfPages = streamIDs.Length + 1;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed this problem using the below code.

Thanks for your help.

```
int pageCount;
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(pdfContent);
using (var r = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string pdfText = r.ReadToEnd();
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regx = new Regex(@"/Type\s*/Page[^s]");
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matches = regx.Matches(pdfText);
    pageCount = matches.Count;
}
```

Comment: Good and beatiful answer, simple and without external dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Save the PDF stream. Use an iTextSharp reference to open the PDF on the server and count pages.