# Getting number of pages from a pdf read as a memory stream in iTextSharp5 rather then file system?

Tags: c#, itext

Using iTextSharp 5 I am trying to get the number of pages of a PDF file that I am pulling thru a memory stream.

```
using (var inms = new MemoryStream(file.Image))//file.Image is a byte array
{
       var reader = new PdfReader(inms);
       var pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
}
```

When I do this pageCount always comes out as 1 even though there are 18 pages in the document.

```
using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(filePath)) 
{
       var pageCount = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
 }
```

When I use the second method and read the document as a file from the file system it returns the expected 18 pages.

Any ideas on why this is and how to get around it?

Comment: if you need it from stream, then you may need to read it as string and find occurances of page in the file. Like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158067/how-to-get-page-count-of-pdf-byte-array-generated-through-ssrs/24668552

Comment: Itext always essentially does load the pdf the same way, no matter if it loads from stream or file. Thus, the byte array in your `file.Image` does not have the same content as the file `filePath`.

Comment: @Vishnu *"if you need it from stream, then you may need to read it as string and find occurances of page in the file."* - no. If one can use a pdf library, there is no need to use that hack.